# Global boolean not working within function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, boolean, global

```
<script>
var xTurn = true;
function changeImage()
{
    element=document.getElementById('myimage')
    if (element.src.match("/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/squaree.png") && xTurn)
    {
        xTurn = false;
        element.src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/xx.png";
    }
    else if (element.src.match("/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/squaree.png") && xTurn==false);
    {
        xTurn = true;
        element.src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/circ.png";
    }
}
</script>

<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/squaree.png" width="90" height="90">
```

For some reason xTurn doesn't seem to work within this function. Am I referencing if incorrectly? This is in wordpress, by the way. I have already checked to make sure the image changes without xTurn being used.

Comment: xTurn should be visible within that function closure. My guess is there is something else wrong with you code. Try `console.log(xTurn)`

Comment: you do the same check twice: element.src.match("/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/squaree.png") but at some point you change the image to xx.png then none of your conditions is met

Comment: Well, initially I want the image to be a square, then after its changed I want it to remain an x or circle, then the next time an image that is a square is clicked it will be an x or circle dependent on the last image, so the logic I have seems right. Its working now. Heres what it looks like: http://pastebin.com/HjH7Dr5T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using match wrong and element.src will give you the complete url with

```
http://domain....
```

try something like

```
element.src.indexOf("squaree") != -1
```

Comment: What is xTerm? And what do you mean by attaching it to the window object? Your example works fine, I had to add the conditional to check whether it was the original image or not (as you can see in my original code) outside the if(xTurn) conditional. What is the correct syntax for if(boolean && boolean){//code} because it doesn't seem to be working for me! First day using javascript... sigh..

Comment: Huh? It seems to work now, did you edit your answer? The code you had before worked for me, but I had to add additional if statements inside the if(xTurn) conditional to meet my requirements. Haven't figured out how to use && correctly, but I'll look that up on my own. Thanks!

Comment: didn't edit it.. you are using && correctly .. but I would use && !xTurn

Comment: also remove the ";" in this part...that might be a issue  png") && xTurn==false);